# space in the beginning of the console when printing in emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm trying to output the string "*you can start typing here*" on the console but it displays a big gap before the text as the picture shows.  One line down and indented many columns.

[image: screenshot]

IDK what the problem is.
i'm using **emu8086 assembly**

```
DATA SEGMENT
str1 DB "you can start typing here : $"
ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
MOV ax,DATA
MOV ds,ax
MOV es, ax

start:
;displaying msg
mov dx, offset str1
mov ah, 09H
int 21h

;END of PROG
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21h

ENDS
end start

ret
```

Comment: When you single-step the code in the debugger built-in to emu8086, does execution start at the top of `CODE SEGMENT`?  If it starts at `start:`, then DS and ES wouldn't have been initialized correctly.

Comment: Since the last line says `end start` which sets the entry point, that should in fact be the case.

Comment: thank you @PeterCordes i've changed the place of start: just before code segment starts and now it works

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but [What happens if you don't add start: and end start in EMU8086?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58902858) is kind of the opposite problem.  Tempted to close it anyway since that points out exactly what `end start` does, and single-step debugging likely would have found the problem here (that the init code doesn't execute).